# Python SimpleKML: Parsing JSON object to string for KML generation

Tags: python, json, list, simplekml

I am looping through the amount of IP addresses in a traceroute and getting the geo-locational data from ip-api.com, I have then added the data that has been passed back into a variable called info.

```
def toKML(iplist,namelist):
    kml = simplekml.Kml()
    x = 0 
    for ip in iplist:
        url =urllib2.Request('http://ip-api.com/json/' + str(ip)) #using API to gather geo info 

        info =json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url)) # setting data value to the feedback from the API for each IP
        if 'city' in info:
            print info['lon']
            kml.newpoint(name=str(info['city']),coords=[str(info['lon']),str(info['lat'])],description=(namelist[x]))
            x += 1
        else:
            print "Geo-locational data not found for the ip "+ ip +"."
            x +=1

    kml.save("test.kml")
```

An example of the JSON Object returned by the API is as follows:

```
{"as":"AS15169 Google Inc.","city":"Mountain View","country":"United    States","countryCode":"US","isp":"Google","lat":37.386,"lon":-122.0838,"org":"Google","query":"8.8.8.8","region":"CA","regionName":"California","status":"success","timezone":"America/Los_Angeles","zip":"94040"}
```

This produces a KML document yet it isn't parsing the coordinates correctly, here is an exerpt of the KML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
    <Document id="feat_1">
        <Placemark id="feat_2">
            <name/>
            <Point id="geom_0">
                <coordinates>-,0,. 5,1,.</coordinates>
            </Point>
            <description>sgyl-core-2b-ae7-717.network.virginmedia.net</description>
        </Placemark>
```

The coordinates are correct within the JSON object as when I print the 'lon' values within 'info'it returns:

> -0.13
>   -0.0931
>   -0.0931
>   -0.13
>   -0.13
>   -0.13
>   -122.1826
>   -6.2597
>   -6.2597
>   -6.2597
>   -122.1822
>   -0.0931
>   -0.0931
>   -122.1822

The error resides within the code:

```
kml.newpoint(name=str(info['city']),coords=[str(info['lon']),str(info['lat'])],description=(namelist[x]))
```

Any help on the matter is greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) your code is poorly formated, please try to edit it a little; 2) add full error message to your question (because the error message will say where exactly is your error.

Comment: Sorry I lose the formatting when I paste into stackoverflow, apologies I am new to all of this. Everything after my method definition should be tabbed in by one, but I can't get it to paste properly I have no idea why.

Comment: but since formatting is important in python, it's very hard to understand your code - where some statement starts and ends, what is inside a function and what is not, and so on. Just click edit and fix it - or better yet, make sure the code in your programming environment does not contain tabs, copy it, paste it into your question, select the code and click **{}** to mark it as a code.

Comment: Just fixed it, thank you for being patient with me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I deciphered some parts of your code. You need to fix several things:

1. `==` is equality comparison operator. `=` is the assignment.
2. do not use `data.insert(x,info); x += 1` to add an item to a list, instead use just `data.append(info)`
3. you read json (and it is parsed into a python dictionary) and store it into `info` variable:

   ```
   info = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))
   ```

   and then you put it into `data` list. So when you try to do:

   ```
   city[counter] == str(data['city'])
   ```

   (beside the `==` vs. `=` confusion), you're trying to index a list `city` with a `counter`, which is actually an item of `data` list, which is a dictionary, hence the error.

But I suspect there will be many other errors, it is probably impossible to help you with all of them.

**EDIT1:** I've tried to estimate how that code probably could look like (but of
course, I don't know exactly what do you want..I'm guessing, since I'm not
familiar with KML):

```
def toKML(iplist, namelist):
    kml = simplekml.KML()
    for ip, name in zip(iplist, namelist):
        url = urllib2.Request('http://ip-api.com/json/' + str(ip))
        info = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))
        kml.newpoint(name=str(info['city']),
                     coords=[(str(info['lon']), str(info['lat']))],
                     description=name)

    kml.save('test.kml') # don't know what this should do, but I'm guesing
                         # saving to a file?
```

Notes:

- I'm not sure if you need to call `str` on every value - from what you've shown us, it looks like it's all strings already
- I don't know if you really want to just save it or return it from that function?

**EDIT 2**: as for your problem with coordinates - I don't know what exactly you need to have in `coords`, but if your `json` looks ike you said it looks like, you're passing:

```
coords=[("-122.0838", "37.386")]
```

to the `kml.newpoint` function. I really do not know if that is correct or not. You should check what format is expected in this function and convert data appropriately.

Also - don't use that `x` to index `namelist` - it's unnecessary, it may cause problems if you're not careful - just use the `zip` as I've shown you (assuming that `namelist` and `iplist` have both the same length). If you don't know what `zip` does - it takes two lists and takes variables from the same positions in the lists when iterating. For example:

```
>>> for a, b in zip([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']):
...  print a, b
... 
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

Not only is it shorter, but also less error prone (you don't have to keep
track of some index number).

Finally - I really, really, really recomend you to read some python tutorial and play with some simple problems in python before trying something more complex. The more you lear, the more fun you'll have with python, instead this suffering I see here. Good luck.

Comment: I originally had a single '=' but then I was trying random things as I am doubting myself here. Thanks for clearing that up.

I guess what I am trying to do is keep the information held in the first index of the city list the same as the index of everything else, which will make plotting the points to the KML document organised, but in doing so I am in way over my head in terms of complication.

Comment: @uvZ_ no problem, thats what this site is for - but you have so many problems in your code, and it is not even complete, so it's hard to provide a complete answer. I think you should try to isolate them into smaller functions, doing very simple things and test every each such function, to see what it really does. Also, I would really recommend reading some python tutorial, for example this one is simple and fun to read: http://www.swaroopch.com/notes/python/

Comment: Thank you so much for that code exerpt, it allowed for the KML document to be generated. I have amended my code quite a lot and I realised I was grossly over complicating things yet I have a new error, which I have highlighted. Your help so far has been invaluable.

Comment: @uvZ_ I think you're not supposed to edit your question if you have a new problem - you should've asked a new question. I'll edit the answer, but next time, just ask another question, ok?